# c++ code doesn't catch exception on FreeBSD

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch, freebsd

I have a program running on many different linux distros. When I compile it on FreeBSD 10.1 for some reason the catch clauses stop working and exceptions that should get caught crash my program. When debugging I modified one of the catch clauses to "catch (...)" and still the exception wasn't caught. I guess the issue is related to the linker, but I don't know how to debug it futher. When I tried compiling a test program that simply throws and catches and exception it worked - so I guess the linker fails to link the different objects properly.

Anyone know how can I solve it?
Thanks

EDIT:
compilation examples (original paths in the commands are longer, deleted them for clarity):

I compiled many classes like this:

```
/usr/local/bin/g++ -O3 -c   -DFreeBSD  -D_FreeBSD  -I. -I/usr/local/openjdk8/include -I/usr/local/openjdk8/include/freebsd -DBOOL_DEFINED -D_BOOL -DFreeBSD -fPIC -I../../../../common/cpp -DVERSION_MAJOR=8 -DVERSION_MIDDLE=2 -DVERSION_MINOR=8 -DNSC_DEBUG -DUSE_HINT_FILES -o CNBCommand.o CNBCommand.cpp
```

then create an archive with

```
ar srv "bin/FreeBSD_10.1-RELEASE/mechanism.a" <many .o files compiled like above>
```

And the final executable is linked with:

```
/usr/local/bin/g++ -O3  -B/usr/local/bin -rpath=/usr/local/lib -lstdc++ -lpthread  -o "../bin/FreeBSD_10.1-RELEASE/nbstatus" <many *.o files compiled like above> bin/FreeBSD_10.1-RELEASE/mechanism.a
```

This is the g++ I use:

```
/usr/local/bin/g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/usr/local/bin/g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/libexec/gcc49/gcc/x86_64-portbld-freebsd10.1/4.9.3/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-portbld-freebsd10.1
Configured with: ./../gcc-4.9-20141126/configure --disable-nls --enable-gnu-indirect-function --libdir=/usr/local/lib/gcc49 --libexecdir=/usr/local/libexec/gcc49 --program-suffix=49 --with-as=/usr/local/bin/as --with-gmp=/usr/local --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/local/lib/gcc49/include/c++/ --with-ld=/usr/local/bin/ld --with-pkgversion='FreeBSD Ports Collection' --with-system-zlib --with-ecj-jar=/usr/local/share/java/ecj-4.5.jar --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,fortran,java --prefix=/usr/local --mandir=/usr/local/man --infodir=/usr/local/info/gcc49 --build=x86_64-portbld-freebsd10.1
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.3 20141126 (prerelease) (FreeBSD Ports Collection)
```

Comment: It's hard for us to tell what your code does, when we haven't seen it, or the options you use for compiling and linking. "Disable exceptions" is one possible compiler option...

Comment: Your compiler on FreeBSD must have different default settings.

Comment: Thanks for your responses, I edited the question and added more information.

Comment: @Surt I don't think it is default compiler setting because my test program compile with the same compiler managed to catch an exception

Comment: @ItamarBe, then we need to minimal code that shows the problem. Something like. `int main() { try { thorw "it"; } catch(...) { printf("caught\n");  } return 0 }`

Comment: @ItamarBe then it must be your code, which you haven't provided. You need to whittle it down to a minimal example which still provokes the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to link with `-Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib/gcc<VERSION>` or you'll link against `libc++`, which doesn't match the headers gcc uses.

Check `pkg info -Dx gcc` for the right path.

Comment: Thanks @kamikaze! works like a charm
i had /usr/loca/lib hardcoded in my Makefile, will change it to discover the location automatically.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you enforce gcc as compiler in first place?