# Exception not caught when compiled with -O2 or -O3 flag

Tags: c++, gcc, exception

I encountered problem when compiling example below with GCC with -O2 or -O3 flag.

```
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

class Args {
    public:
        Args(int, char** argv);

        const std::string get_arg() const;

    private:
        int argc_;
        int index_ = 0;
        char** argv_;
};

Args::Args(int argc, char** argv):
    argc_(argc),
    argv_(argv)
{
}

const std::string Args::get_arg() const
{
    if (index_ >= argc_) {
        throw std::out_of_range("Out of range.");
    }

    return std::string(argv_[index_]);
}

int main(int, char** argv)
{
    Args args(0, argv);

    try {
        std::string a = args.get_arg(); // Must throw.
        std::cout << "After get_arg(): " << a << std::endl;
    } catch(std::out_of_range) {
        std::cout << "Catched" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When the example is compiled with -O3 flag

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic -Wextra -O3 -g0 -o args args.cpp
```

exception `std::out_of_range` is not caught in the catch blok. Output is

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  Out of range.
Abort trap
```

Everything works if the example is compiled with GCC without -O2 or -O3

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic -Wextra -g0 -o args args.cpp
```

or with CLang

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic -Wextra -O3 -g0 -o args args.cpp
clang++ -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic -Wextra -g0 -o args args.cpp
```

Version of GCC: (FreeBSD Ports Collection) 5.4.0
Version of CLang: 4.0.0
OS: FreeBSD 11.1 (amd64)

Where is the bug?

Comment: "where is the bug?": freebsd. Just from the title of your question, I guessed what your system was...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for navigating. I found right solution in this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/33279425/8838989. It works when example is compiled with flags `-Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib/gcc5`

```
g++5 -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic -Wextra -O3 -g0 -Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib/gcc5 -o args args.cpp
```